# How can I prove that no derivative exist withing this function?

Tags: calculus

Our teacher challenge us a question and it goes like this: 
The derivative of a function is define such as

$$\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x>0 \\  2 & \text{if } x=0 \\ -1 &\text{if } x<0\end{cases} $$

Now he said that "$2$, if $x=0$" is not possible.He asked us to proved that the derivative at $x=0$ does not exist without using the concept of limit or using graphical intuition such as the slope of tangent but using only verbal words without resorting to use limit.

Comment: Could words like neighborhood be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Note this function doesn't satisfy the intermediate value property on $[-1,1]$. By [Darboux's theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)), there is no function $g$ such that $g'(x) = f(x) \forall x \in [-1, 1]$.In other words, $f$ is not the derivative on $[-1, 1]$ of any function.

Comment: How did you deduce discontinuity of $f$ from that of $f'$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I have modified my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might think about the fact that aside from $x=0$ this is the derivative of the absolute value function, which does not have a derivative at $x=0$ You excluded using many things, but did not say what is allowed.  You could let $f(0)=a$, then use the fundamental theorem of calculus to get $f(x)$ for all $x$ and show how there is no derivative at $0$.

Comment: Just a comment of a neophite but... what happen with distribution theory? I means, it is defined a derivative of absolute value and many others discontinuous functions.

Comment: @Masacroso:  I think we are at a much lower level with this question.  It looks to me first year calculus.  Even so, what value would you assign for $f'(0)?$  I think distributions do not care about the value at a point.